# Mapview zoom level changes when going to other activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

In one of my first activity i had a small portion of mapview and i did it. when clicking on the mapview it sholud load another activity which contains the full mapview.
(Second activity).i second activity if i zoom the map and go back to the first activity the map is showing a zoomed as like the first activity. but i need not want this.
 In first activity the zoom level should be static.Any one plz help in this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you disabled zooming in the first mapview? Show us some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    mapController.setZoom(10);
    mapController.animateTo(animatePoint);
}
```

use the above code might solve your problem ..... my work around to this problem which i faced recently. First try it in FirstActivity

Comment: hi where i need to add the onRestart() is it on second activity